# Interface depictions in communication diagram or System sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, communication-diagram

I was searching around for a simple example depiction on how it would look if  class Professor and Class Student would both implement and interface from Class Person in a **communication diagram** or **System sequence diagram**.

I think its depicted as this a class diagram:

[image]

But i am curious if it can be depicted in a **communication diagram** or **System sequence diagram** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show anything in any diagram type. Citing p. 683 of UML 2.5:

> **NOTE.** This taxonomy provides a logical organization for the various major kinds of diagrams. However, it does not preclude mixing different kinds of diagram types, as one might do when one combines structural and behavioral elements (e.g., showing a state machine nested inside an internal structure). Consequently, the boundaries between the various kinds of diagram types are not strictly enforced.

I think, that's more than clear.

Comment: Do you have an simple example showing how an interface would look in a interaction diagram (java)?

Comment: Just like your  drawing. An interaction diagram per se is a behavioral one. So you would show method invocations of  operations defined the interface. The drawing above would just accompany that. A bit pointless though, since it does not show any operations.